# Array: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing this program and have checked other similar posts too. But I have difficulty understanding how can I solve this?

Here is html

```
<body>
<h1>Hello!</h1> Please input start and end of your numbers
<input type="text" id="start" value="1" />
<input type="text" id="end" value="10" />
<button id="btn" onclick="MyFunc(document.getElementById('start').value, document.getElementById('end').value)">Click Me</button>
```

and here is JS script:

```
function MyFunc(start, end) {
    for(i=start;i<end;i++)
    {
        var arr = [];
        arr[i].push;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I want to construct an array sequence from the first and last values input by user, and then show the array/perform some calculations. I have reviewed other answers at Stack, but couldn't sort out whats wrong with this.

Thank you.

Comment: seems like you confusing `arr[i].push;` with `arr.push(i);`. Anyway in `demo` element you always see last value, because you use `=` instead `+=`

Comment: also your function can work wrong, because you pass to it _strings_, but expect _number_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring an empty array `var arr = []`. Right after that you are accessing its contents so for sure it doesn't have any contents so `arr[i]` is `undefined`.

I think what you are trying to do is

```
function MyFunc(start, end) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    var str = "";
    for(i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        str += i;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/evs1o0oc/3/)**

Comment: try input _11_ to start and _3_ to end :-)

Comment: It prints 11 :D. There is no validation involved at the moment. That's up to the asker :)

Comment: just use `parseInt` not in loop body, but before like `parseInt(start)` and `parseInt(end)` ;-)

Comment: @Incongnite Thanks, this worked. However, I worry what was wrong with my code in the first place? Only the change of = to += ?!!!

Comment: @Incognito, you not using array, so, i think better delete it

Comment: @Zafar, first of all, you are saving the values in the array incorrectly by using `arr[i].push;`. Secondly, you are just overwriting the `#demo` by using just `=`, better concatenate using `+=`.

Comment: @Grundy, how am I not using arrays?

Comment: @Incognito, `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i;`, you push to local array, and not return it, so if you remove it function befavior not changed

Comment: Ah I see, I understand now. Thanks for spotting that @Grundy. Sorry I misunderstood the first time. Editing now.

Answer (score -3):

**Change**

`var arr= [];`

**To**

`var arr= new Array(size);` // size needs to be an integer value.

Also declare the array before the `for loop`

You always have to initialize an array before adding/removing elements from the same. Since the `arr` array was not defined, you got a `TypeError`

Comment: How can I know the size of an array in advance, if I don't know what the user will type in form?

Comment: `new Array(size);` not fill array elements with some default value, so `a[i]` anyway _undefined_, and not matter how you create array `Array(size)` or just `[]`